# portfolio optimization - unable to retrieve attribute for 'x'

Tags: python, pandas, gurobi

I am learning how to use Gurobi optimizer and here is the sample code for portfolio optimization.

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
from math import sqrt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create historical return data for two stocks
equity1 = [0.0107, 0.0122, 0.076, 0.084, 0.0207]
equity2 = [0.0133, 0.0278, 0.0719, 0.0353, 0.0163]
data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(equity1, equity2)), columns = ['SPX', 'FXAIX']) 
stocks = data.columns

# Calculate basic summary statistics for individual stocks
stock_volatility = data.std()
stock_return = data.mean()

# Create an empty model
m = gp.Model('portfolio')

# Add a variable for each stock
vars = pd.Series(m.addVars(stocks), index=stocks)

# Objective is to minimize risk (squared).  This is modeled using the
# covariance matrix, which measures the historical correlation between stocks.

sigma = data.cov()
portfolio_risk = sigma.dot(vars).dot(vars)
m.setObjective(portfolio_risk, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Fix budget with a constraint
m.addConstr(vars.sum() == 1, 'budget')

# Optimize model to find the minimum risk portfolio
m.setParam('OutputFlag', 0)
m.optimize()

# Create an expression representing the expected return for the portfolio
portfolio_return = stock_return.dot(vars)

# Display minimum risk portfolio
print('Minimum Risk Portfolio:\n')
for v in vars:
    if v.x > 0:
        print('\t%s\t: %g' % (v.varname, v.x))

minrisk_volatility = sqrt(portfolio_risk.getValue())

minrisk_return = portfolio_return.getValue()

# Solve for efficient frontier by varying target return
frontier = pd.Series(dtype=np.float64)

for r in np.linspace(stock_return.min(), stock_return.max(), 100):
    m.addConstr(portfolio_return == r, 'target')  
    m.optimize()
    print(portfolio_risk.getValue()) 
    #frontier.loc[sqrt(portfolio_risk.getValue())] = r
```

I got the error "Unable to retrieve attribute 'x' for the last line of code somehow when I try to create an efficient frontier. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First, two important suggestions:

1. Always check the [Status code](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/optimization_status_codes.html) to see the status of a call to Model.optimize()
2. For debugging, never disable logging, so comment out the line that sets the parameter OutputFlag=0

With logging, I get this output:

```
Barrier solved model in 0 iterations and 0.00 seconds
Model is infeasible or unbounded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(portfolio_risk.getValue()) 
  File "src/gurobipy/quadexpr.pxi", line 404, in gurobipy.QuadExpr.getValue
  File "src/gurobipy/var.pxi", line 125, in gurobipy.Var.__getattr__
  File "src/gurobipy/var.pxi", line 153, in gurobipy.Var.getAttr
  File "src/gurobipy/attrutil.pxi", line 100, in gurobipy.__getattr
AttributeError: Unable to retrieve attribute 'x'
```

So to resolve the underlying issue, follow the instructions in the Gurobi knowledgebase article: [How do I resolve the error "Model is infeasible or unbounded"](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402704428177-How-do-I-resolve-the-error-Model-is-infeasible-or-unbounded-).